# VScode cannot find the `action_sheet.dart`

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I downloaded `flutter 2.5` and updated the `flutter SDK path` in `system env variables` under `path` in `windows system variables`. When I run the emulator it shows errors in the `debug console` in `vscode`. But `Flutter doctor` shows no errors.

**Error**

> ../../flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/cupertino.dart:25:1:
> Error: Error when reading
> '../../flutter_windows_2.2.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/action_sheet.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> export 'src/cupertino/action_sheet.dart'; ^ 2
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I can clearly see it's looking for some file in the `old path`. I guess I need to change the path somewhere else as well. Where do I have to update the `new path` other than `windows env variables`?

Comment: have you tried to clear VS studio cache?

Comment: @Csisanyi : Yes it doesn't work

Comment: I would also try ```flutter clean``` than ```flutter pub get```